# How can I install only the basics in Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I want to install a light distro on my laptop, and I want to use it in text mode. I just want to use `gcc`, `nano`, `ghci`, `javac` and some text browser. But when I installed using the CD, the first installation disk ended up installing many packages that I will not use, and I wanted to leave my computer as light as possible.

How can I choose just the essential packages that I need for the basics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you boot the live CD, select "expert install" (graphical or non-graphical; it doesn't matter). Follow the installation. When it gets to the screen to "select additional software to install" or whatever, unselect everything. Then proceed with the installation.

This will leave you in a minimal environment (essentially just `base` and anything marked "essential").

Comment: There's a command for that! (just in case it's useful someday)
`aptitude -s --without-recommends -o APT::Install-Recommends=no -y install ~prequired ~pimportant ~pstandard`

I suppose standard priority isn't required if you want to be really minimal.  Remove the -s when you see what is to be installed.